# In COBOL when will the following Until condition evaluate to true

Tags: cobol

```
01 ws-var-05 pic x value 'n'.
   88 ws-var-88 value 'y'
01 ws-var-2 pic 9 value 1.
   88 ws-var-88-2 value 2.

.
.
.
* comment ws-var-88-2 is set to true when eof is 
* reached in the at end clause of read statement
* need to understand when ws-var-05 evaluates to 
* true! Is this right syntax? What happens if we use 
* this syntax? Need to understand if this is a 
* defect

Perform 1000-para until ws-var-88-2 or ws-var-05.
```

Comment: Your question is only answerable by inspection of the part of the code that sets the variable you are asking about. By you.

Answer (score 2):

The line...

```
Perform 1000-para until ws-var-88-2 or ws-var-05.
```

...contains a syntax error, at least when compiled with GNU COBOL 1.1.0.

The `UNTIL` clause of the `PERFORM` verb can contain conditional expressions.  One type of conditional expression is a "condition-name condition" which is an 88-level. However, the name of an identifier (in this case `ws-var-05`) must be followed by a conditional operator (<, >, =, etc.) and then either another identifier or a literal for the `UNTIL` clause to be valid.

> Is this right syntax?

No.

> What happens if we use this syntax?

A compile-time error will occur.

Answer (score 0):

Several things.

It is very much a "best practice" to leave the storage that backs your conditional items (88s) unnamed.  This prevents people from accidentally moving the wrong value into them and causing subtle bugs.

For example, this:

```
01 ws-var-05 pic x value 'n'.
   88 ws-var-88 value 'y'
01 ws-var-2 pic 9 value 1.
   88 ws-var-88-2 value 2.
```

Is better written as this:

```
01                pic x value 'n'.
   88 ws-var-88 value 'y'.
01                pic 9 value 1.
   88 ws-var-88-2 value 2.
```

So nobody can ever accidentally do a "Move 'Y' to ws-var-05".  This is especially problematic on mainframes, where there are some automatic uppercasing editor options that could really make the difference between 'y' and 'Y' hard to notice.

In the case of this, there are several things, the ws-var-05 is not a complete conditional, you could use "ws-var-88 or ws-var-88-2" and it would be a complete conditional.

You don't need a period at the end, and its use can often be problematic with modern compilers.  Since Cobol-85, the END-verbname is the preferred way to terminate a command.  You could write this:

```
Perform 1000-para until ws-var-88-2 or ws-var-05.
```

as:

```
Perform 1000-para until (ws-var-88 or ws-var-88-2)
```

or, IMNSHO, a clearer and cleaner approach, as it separates your terminate condition from the commands you will be executing in the body of the perform:

```
Perform until (ws-var-88-2 or ws-var-88-2)
   Perform 1000-para
End-Perform
```

I will also always use parens to delimit my intended order of operations, though in this case, it matters not.  For more complicated conditions, they can be a big help for the on-call programmer that has to look at something blowing up at 3am.

You trigger your terminal conditionals like so:

```
1000-para.
   Read myfile
     at end
       set ws-var-88-2 to true
   End-Read
   If (something-else = time-to-quit)
       set ws-var-88 to true
   End-If
   Exit.  *> One of the few places you need a period
          *> in modern cobol, adding the "Exit" or 
          *> "Continue" NOPs clearly calls out to a
          *> reader that you are using a period.
```